# Strapi v4.9.0 cannot create custom Plugin - not shown in Admin Panel Side Bar

Tags: plugins, strapi

I have been working with strapi v4.9.0 and i need to create a custom plugin which will allow to export my content-type data base entries into a downloadable CSV file. Now, I know that plugins for that already exist, but I need to create my own one (because of dependencies etc. …).

I am programming in typescript and followed this tutorial:  https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins-development#creating-a-plugin

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the plugin is listed under Plugins. But neither in the Admin Side Panel nor in the Settings can I “access” the plugin. I checked the plugin folder structure, and nothing seems to miss.
Also I re-build the project several times, deleted the cache, reinstalled node_modules/ and registered the plugin in config/plugins.ts as shown in the tutorial.

Does someone here has any suggestion as to why I cannot seem to make this work?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Already explained in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, `npm` was to blame, it has issues with strapi, delete your dist folders from plugin and from strapi, also delete the package-lock.json from plugin and from strapi, and also the node_modules folders.

Install everything again using yarn. If you don't have yarn, install it using `npm i yarn -g`, restart the cmd.

Build the plugin firstly and then strapi, then you can try it `yarn develop --watch-admin`